# Hapi.js - Logging best practices

Tags: javascript, hapi.js

I am trying to set up logging to file for Hapi.js, but I am failing to that task.

I just need a logging facility to a file, and when I request it.

I have followed [good-console](https://github.com/hapijs/good) and I got it to log my system status to a file automatically. That is fine, but how do I do it manually?

For example:

```
 myRouteMethod: function(request, reply){
    var projectId = request.params.projectid;
    //How Do I log projectId????
}
```

Comment: Look at Good File: https://github.com/hapijs/good-file.

Comment: `request.log(['some', 'tags'], projectId)` and make sure you're listening to request events with the appropriate tags.

Comment: http://hapijs.com/api#requestlogtags-data-timestamp

Comment: Where is it saved?

Comment: wherever you configure it to be saved